# vscode TreeItem icon with http URI

Tags: vscode-extensions, content-security-policy

In my own vscode extension, I have implemented my own TreeDataProvider and my own TreeItem.
I want to set Icons on my TreeItems.
A possible type of `iconPath` of TreeItems is `Uri`.
When I try to set an `http://my.site/my/icon/Icon.svg` Uri to my TreeItems, I've got an execution error with the following message : "Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources, Resource `http://my.site/my/icon/Icon.svg` is blocked for directive img-src"

How to set a Content Security Policy for Uri in a vscode extension (I'm not in a Webview, I'm in a Tree) ?
Is it possible to set `http...` icon paths for TreeItems ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set your own CSP outside of a webview. The tree can only show icons from trusted websites or from local file system.

Unfortunately I cannot find the place in the documentation where this is mentioned. I only remember that Github is one of the trusted sources.